# Problem in openlayers wfs-t with geoserver 2.7?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

I'm using [OpenLayers-3](http://openlayers.org). I have a wfs layer. I want to sync this layer with my server as follow(I use [geoserver 2.7-SNAPSHOT](http://geoserver.org/) and my datastore's type is shapefile):

```
var opt = {
    featureType: "Calk:Point",
    featureNS: "http://itsme.calk.org",
    srsName: "EPSG:4326"
}
var s = new XMLSerializer();

var url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs";

var node = wfs.writeTransaction(InsertFeaturesArr, updateFeaturesArr, deleteFeaturesArr, opt);
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'proxy.cgi?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    method: 'POST',
    xmlData: s.serializeToString(node),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    },
    success: function(response_) {
        response = response_;
    }
});
```

It create a payload request as follow:

```
<Transaction 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">

    <Insert>
        <Point xmlns="http://itsme.calk.ir">
            <the_geom>
                <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                    <pos>44.53857421875 25.492868271257123</pos>
                </Point>
            </the_geom>
                ...
            <NAME>asdf</NAME>
        </Point>
    </Insert>
    <Update typeName="Calk:Point" xmlns:Calk="http://itsme.calk.ir">
        <Property>
            <Name>the_geom</Name>
            <Value>
                <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                    <pos>29.614517211914062 52.532684326171875</pos>
                </Point>
            </Value>
        </Property>
           ...
        <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <FeatureId fid="Point.21"/>
        </Filter>
    </Update>
    <Delete typeName="Calk:Point" xmlns:Calk="http://itsme.calk.ir">
        <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <FeatureId fid="Point.24"/>
        </Filter>
    </Delete>
</Transaction>
```

It doesn't work properly. Geoserver's response is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:TransactionResponse 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:Calk="http://itsme.calk.ir" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:opengeo="http://opengeo.org" xmlns:usa="http://census.gov" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">

    <wfs:TransactionSummary>
        <wfs:totalInserted>1</wfs:totalInserted>
        <wfs:totalUpdated>2</wfs:totalUpdated>
        <wfs:totalDeleted>3</wfs:totalDeleted>
    </wfs:TransactionSummary>
    <wfs:TransactionResults/>
    <wfs:InsertResults>
        <wfs:Feature>
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="new0"/>
        </wfs:Feature>
    </wfs:InsertResults>
</wfs:TransactionResponse>
```

In this case, it must add a feature with `NAME` property: `asdf`(**it does not add new feature**), and update a feature(**It does not update any feature**), and delete a feature(**It do this correctly**). But when I create 3 request and as follow, It doesn't delete the feature **some times**:

```
var insertNode = wfs.writeTransaction(InsertFeaturesArr, [], [], opt);
Ext.Ajax.request({
    ...
    xmlData: s.serializeToString(insertNode),
    ...
});

var updateNode = wfs.writeTransaction([], updateFeaturesArr [], opt);
Ext.Ajax.request({
    ...
    xmlData: s.serializeToString(updateNode),
    ...
});

var deleteNode = wfs.writeTransaction([], [], deleteFeaturesArr, opt);
Ext.Ajax.request({
    ...
    xmlData: s.serializeToString(deleteNode),
    ...
});
```

**Where is the problem**?
I tested this code with [geoserver 2.8](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver) t0o and it does not correctly too.

Comment: What datastore do you have? PostGIS or shapefile?

Comment: It's shapefile.

Comment: Shapefile datastores cannot be trusted for WFS-T don't use it.

Comment: Could you either share it or repeat your tests with the tiger:poi layer? Only proper way to test is to have same set-up than you have, fire the same requests, and look at the logs. But WFS-T with shapefiles may be good for playing but not for production.

Comment: Does you insert miss typeName? I am not sure if shapefiles has stable feature-IDs so if you originally had IDs 1-25 and you delete ID=24, I don't know if ID=25 exists any more or if it is now ID=24, the last feature in the shapefile. That should be tested. And Geoserver is not good at reporting partial success/failure as you can see from your TransactionSummary. Everything is reported to be right but is not.

Comment: I will use postgis datastore and give notice you.

Comment: I tested it for tiger:poi. The result is same.

Comment: I tested wit posgis `datastore` and I it worked fine. Thanks for your help. If you want put an answer to register with your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Geoserver`](http://geoserver.org) dose not work properly with shape file datastore. For reliable transaction you must define a postgis datastore.